# Server variable UNENCODED_URL contains strange value instead of encoded slash

Tags: c++, url, iis, isapi

We have a legacy IIS DLL that uses `GetServerVariable` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525335(v=vs.90).aspx)) to retrieve the value of `UNENCODED_URL`. When accessing the URL:

```
https://example.com/a%2Fb
```

the value retrieved will look like this:

```
/path/to/server.dll/a0.000000b
```

which is strange, because it should look like this:

```
/path/to/server.dll/a%2Fb
```

The `LPEXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK`'s value of `lpszPathInfo` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525658(v=vs.90).aspx)) has the value:

```
/a/b
```

as expected.

Does anybody know why the `UNENCODED_URL` value looks like this and how can I retrieve the correct value?

Comment: How are you determining the value? You’re not just using `printf` to display it? Because that would explain it

Comment: I'm logging it to a file using some legacy technique. Good point, the logging may misinterprete it, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using for example `printf` to output the value of the environment variable instead of using a debugger, or `puts`, that will explain it. `%2f` will be understood as a command to `printf` to output the first variable argument as a floating point number.

Always output strings with `puts` or other functions that do not alter the value.

Comment: Or use `printf()` with the `%s` specifier to print strings that have `%` characters in them. NEVER pass arbitrary strings to the `format` parameter of `printf()`, only strings that you create yourself for the purpose of formatting.